# Side-by-side web parts on a wiki page: possible?

Tags: web-part, wiki

I want to have two small web parts (weather and traffic reports) arranged side-by-side, rather than one on top of the other, on a wiki page (Home.aspx). It appears that I'll need a web part zone to do this, but it also appears that I [cannot add a secondary](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/f82be255-ae1f-42bd-9bac-318b5c6759ff/) web part to a [wiki page.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496201/how-to-add-a-web-part-zone-to-a-sharepoint-wiki-page) Or can I?

Honestly, the web part zone issue is just how I'm thinking I might have to solve the side-by-side issue, but if there's a better way, I'm all ears!

This is under SharePoint Foundation 2010, FWIW.

Comment: Please **tag by feature** and not by version or product. This helps to attract more attention to your question and keep it relevant. See [How do I use tags](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264/) for general guidelines. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add as many web parts to a wiki page as you want.

You can use either the Text Layout button (on Ribbon) to do things like split the page up into multiple columns.

If that doesn't give you granular enough control then add a table (use Insert > Table) with 1 row and 2 cols and add the web parts into the cells.

Comment: I am sure some CSS nazi will be long in a minute telling me how I've just killed a puppy for suggesting that tables be used for layout purposes ;)

Comment: Someone called? :P

Answer (score 3):

If you have SharePoint Designer installed, you should be able to use it to create a custom page layout with more WebPart zones.

When I did it, I believe I used this site: http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=940&page=2.  The site shows a MOSS2007 site, but I believe it worked for 2010 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add a table using Ribbon Controls with 1 row and 2 cols and add the web parts into the cells.

Check this it helps

http://techwirenews.com/2012/04/26/creating-a-custom-web-page-in-sharepoint-2010/